# Delegation in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates

When the user pressed an 'add' button a modal view pops up for them to enter information. I have a 'cancel' button in the top left of a navigation bar and I want it to dismiss the current view controller when it is pressed. How do I set an object as the class's delegate? I understand creating protocols and implementing its methods but I cannot seem to make the delegate be set. When running the debugger my `[self delegate]` in the 'add' view controller is always `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you spawning the modal viewController through a segue set up in your Storyboard? If so, then in the `prepareForSegue:` method you would set the delegate there.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{ 
    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"userGuideSegue_home"]){
        UserGuideViewController* vc = segue.destinationViewController;
          [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
    }

}
```

On the other hand, if you are setting up the modal viewController entirely through code, then you would create an instance of the modal viewController then set it's delegate.

```
- (void)showModelView:(NSString*)viewName
{
    // code ripped out of project so a bit specific

    if ([viewName isEqualToString:@"userGuide_name"]) {
        modalViewController = (UserGuideViewController * )
        [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:NULL] 
         instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserGuide"];
    }

    modalViewController.delegate = self;
    modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    modalViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    modalViewController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];; 


    [self presentViewController:modalViewController 
                       animated:YES 
                     completion:^{
                         //put your code here
                     }];
}
```

Of course all this assumes you have defined a `delegate` property on your modal viewController.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the view in IB, Control-drag the button into the ViewController's header file and add an IBOutlet.  Inside of that method in the .m file you can

`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

alternatively you can create the button programmatically:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(processCancel:)];

-(void)processCancel:(UIBarButtonItem *)item{
     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
  id delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) id delegate;
@synthesize delegate;
```

This should do the job, you can now use `[MyViewController setDelegate:self]` before showing the modal view and call `[[self delegate] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` in the cancel button tapped event in `MyViewController`